# Sonar "Make transient or serializable" error

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization

I have the following serializable class (implements serializable):

```
public class Test implements Serializable{

private String id;

private Map<String,Object> otherProperties;

}
```

However , it seems like this property is causing some problems with serialization :

[image]

How can I solve this problem ?

Also , is there any downside in not making this transient or serializable ? Will I be able to serialize this class fully ?

Comment: https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1948

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `Map` interface does **not** extend the `Serializable` interface, which is why Sonar is warning you.

When serializing an instance of `Test`, you must choose whether or not you want `otherProperties` to be serialized.

If you **don't** want to serialize `otherProperties`, then the field should be marked as `transient`:

```
private transient Map<String, Object> otherProperties;
```

Otherwise, you can change the type of `otherProperties` to an implementation of `Map` that implements `Serializable`, such as `HashMap`.

Comment: If we change the otherProperties to the type HashMap or anyother implementation of Map interface, sonar will raise another issue to force us to use the Interface type in variables.

Comment: if we do this then in Criteria Mata model that filed will be deleted .

Comment: Added HashMap but this still does not work for me since Sonar does not know if Object is serializable.

Answer (score 5):

Change Object to Serializable and then Sonar should be happy.

```
private Map<String, Serializable> otherProperties;
```

Since your class is Serializable its fields also should be Serializable.

Answer (score 4):

Add this 2 methods to your class:

```
 private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream stream)
        throws IOException {
    stream.defaultWriteObject();
}

private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream)
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    stream.defaultReadObject();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's an option (for instance, if you are using Jackson to (de)serialize your class), remove the `Serializable` marker from your `Test` class. The serialization will still work and you will get rid of the warning in Sonar.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue but in contrast to [Nexussim Lements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59252823/4146792) I've been using an interface that gets serialized but still SonarLint showed me a warning:

```
public class BasicCheck implements Serializable { ... }

public class Case implements Serializable {
   private BasicCheck basicCheck; // Sonarlint throws warning here
   ...
}
```

Luckily I've found [FAlfeao's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74626949/4146792) to be working. All I had to do was to add these two methods to my `Case`-class:

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream stream)
        throws IOException {
    stream.defaultWriteObject();
}

private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream)
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    stream.defaultReadObject();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Map value type should be specified to extends Serialzable:

```java
public class Test<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable{

private String id;

private Map<String,T> otherProperties;

}
```